# RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ruby, rvm

I am trying to install [Discourse as explained here](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-ubuntu.md) but the command

```
# Use installed ruby as default
rvm use 2.0.0 --default
```

results in this:

```
discourse@ubuntu:~$ rvm use 2.0.0 --default

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

I understand that

```
For RVM to work properly, you have to set the 'Run command as login shell' checkbox on the Title and Command tab inside of gnome-terminal's Settings page.
```

[as explained here](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal) but I don't have access to GUI, because I am installing through ssh to the ubuntu server. How can I change that setting in gnome?

---

---

**EDIT**

[As per mpapis' answer](https://superuser.com/a/695722/56808) I ran `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` but I still get the same error. I include the output below. Does this tell me about anything to fix?

```
discourse@ubuntu:/var/www/discourse$ rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Turning on auto dotfiles mode.
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /home/discourse/.rvm/
    Removing rvm PATH line from /home/discourse/.profile /home/discourse/.bashrc /home/discourse/.zshrc.
    Adding rvm PATH line to /home/discourse/.profile /home/discourse/.bashrc /home/discourse/.zshrc.
    Removing rvm loading line from /home/discourse/.profile /home/discourse/.zlogin.
    Adding rvm loading line to /home/discourse/.bash_profile /home/discourse/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /home/discourse/.rvm/ is complete.

# discourse,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io
       Help RVM 2.0: https://www.bountysource.com/fundraisers/489-rvm-2-0

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

RVM reloaded!
```

Answer (score 5):

This will work,add these lines to your ~/.bashrc file manually

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 3):

run:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

make sure you read all the output - rvm prints information and warnings for you that you can fix any problems that can not be fixed automatically

Comment: I still get the same error. I updated my question with the output, if you want to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: close the `ssh` connection and connect again, do you login directly to the user or use `su` or `sudo` to change user?

Comment: Logging out and then SSHing in again fixed this issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In '.profile' comment out (or delete) `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` because it is already in '.bashrc' file and move `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to '.bashrc'.